# Are shared views still around in MVC 4 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm brand new to MVC and I was trying to work my way through the music store tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

I could tell right away that things looked slightly different in MVC 4 RC but one big thing I'm hitting is I don't see any Shared View being created when I add a Home View.  In fact I don't see a _Layout* file anywhere within the project.

So my question is, has the shared view thing been replaced by some other mechanism or do I need to do something else to add this explicitly?

Thanks,
JT

Comment: To follow up, I was able to create _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml manually and everything seems to work as expected.  Still curious why it didn't get auto-generated though.

Answer (score 3):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/05/31/announcing-the-release-candidate-rc-of-visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5.aspx:

> If you’re doing web development, you’ll notice a handful of updates in
>   the RC. First off, we’ve updated some of the project templates. We
>   made the MVC4 Empty template truly empty, and renamed the original
>   empty template to now be called the “Basic” template. We also improved
>   the performance of the New Project creation time.

Essentially all of the initial templates have been cut down a lot.  The Empty project doesn't come with a HomeController either - you can add anything you need back.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is tied to how you start the project.  If you select Internet Application when you create a new MVC project it will build these files for you but if you select Empty you have to create them manually.